# injectables not working in angular 2.0 latest build 26

Tags: angular, typescript1.5

I was going thorugh the angular2.0 demo app but it seems that injectables are not working from build 24 and giving me error as 
 "ORIGINAL ERROR: Cannot resolve all parameters for MyAppComponent. Make sure they all have valid type or annotations." 
 till build 23 its working fine ,please help me with the issue 
below is the demo code, i had made few manipulations from the original just for learning purpose

```
import {Component, View, bootstrap, NgFor} from 'angular2/angular2';


module foo{
  class FriendsService {
    names: Array<string>;
    constructor() {
        this.names = ["Alice", "Aarav", "Martín", "Shannon", "Ariana","Kai"];
    }
}


@Component({
    selector: 'array',
    injecetables: [FriendsService]

})
@View({
        template: '<p>My name: {{ myName }}</p><p>Friends:</p><ul><li *ng-for="#name of names">{{ name }}</li></ul>',
        directives: [NgFor]
}) 
   export class arrayComponent {
    myName: string;
    names: Array<string>;

    constructor(friendsService: FriendsService) {
       this.myName = 'Alice';
       this.names = friendsService.names;
     }
   }
 }

bootstrap(foo.arrayComponent);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The new syntax for `injectables` is `appInjector`.

Try:

```
@Component({
  selector: 'array',
  appInjector: [FriendsService]
})
```

Also, you will want to change your imports for `Component` and `View` to:

```
import {ComponentAnnotation as Component, ViewAnnotation as View} from "angular2/angular2";
```

Comment: above solution not working still giving me the same error , is there anything else i am missing in my above code

Comment: `appInjector` has been removed @ alpha.29, this solution will no longer work. Now have to use `hostInjector` or `viewInjector`

Comment: I'm having the same issue mentioned above, I've tried both hostInjector and viewInjector and still the same error. Can you point at something that shows how to use those correctly?

Answer (score 7):

It seems that [the currently latest angular2, alpha-35,](https://code.angularjs.org/2.0.0-alpha.35/angular2.dev.js) replaces `appInjector` with `bindings`.

Like this:

```ts
import {FriendsService} from 'FriendsService';

@Component({
    selector: 'array',
    bindings: [FriendsService]
})
```

I also had to explicitly export `FriendsService`:

```ts
export class FriendsService {
```

[Complete code example here](https://github.com/Mellbourn/angular2-step-by-step-guide)

Comment: @klas-melbourn thank you! I noticed you're not using the `bootstrap()` from the guide - is there a reason why? has `export` supplanted that?

Comment: @ghchinoy I use `bootstrap` in the main `app.ts` file. You only have to do it once, not in every `.ts` file.

Comment: @ghchinoy, if you use `bootstrap()`, then you are using the application-wide injector, and you'll only get one instance of `FriendsService`.  If you use `providers` on the Component (which replaces `bindings`), then you are using the component's injector, and you may get more than one instance of the `FriendsService`.  See my answer for more info.

Answer (score 2):

In Angular 2 there is the application-wide injector and then there are the component injectors.

If you only want one instance of FriendsService across your entire app, then include it in the bootstrap() array:

```
@Component({
   // providers: [FriendsService],
   ...

bootstrap(App, [FriendsService])
```

If you would rather have one instance per component, use the `providers` array in the component's configuration object instead:

```
@Component({
   providers: [FriendsService ],
   ...

bootstrap(App, [])
```

<kbd>[Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/bP9pk1K9c1vQkvKjIhFl)</kbd>

See the [Hierarchical Injectors](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/hierarchical-dependency-injection.html) doc for more info.

Answer (score 0):

> module foo{
>     class FriendsService {...

Your `FriendsService` class is defined within a module which is an issue in two ways:

1. Your class needs to be exported from the module to make it visible outside of `foo`
2. When you reference `FriendsSerivce` you are not specifying that it is inside the `foo` module.

I would suggest completely removing the foo module and rely on the module patterns in amd/commonjs instead. That means you don't need to export the class (assuming they're in the same file) and you don't need to change the reference to the class in your component.

Answer (score 0):

Your `FriendsService` is abstracted within a module and is not being exported, that's why `arrayComponent` can't access it and throws an error.

You should just take out the module and have `foo` be declared above `arrayComponent` in the same scope.

Also, your bootstrap at the end is wrong since `arrayComponent` isn't part of `foo`. Just have it be

`bootstrap(arrayComponent)`

and it should be fine.